# Searching in variables, returning 'string, string2' based on search

Tags: php

I know using `stripos()` i can search in a string and if this string contains my wanted variable, `return 'xx';`

Take a look at the following 4 strings:

```
Power Red/Collegiate Burgundy
Prism Pink,Racer Pink,Mist Blue,Prism Pink
Red/Vintage White/Gold Metallic
Sail,Pure Platinum,University Red,Obsidian
```

So these are all 'color' variations, and i have approximately 3000 variations of all.

There are some keywords that always return, like `Red` , `Blue` , `Burgundy` etcetera.

What i want to accomplish is this:

```
if (stripos($color_string, 'Red') !== false) {
return 'Red';}
```

But there is a problem with this. Using the above code returns `Red` on ALL strings containing `Red`.

What i want is this:

The string `Power Red/Collegiate Burgundy/Black Hard/Silver Paradise` must return `Red, Black, Burgundy, Silver`.

The stripos input will be provided by me, containing all the different color variations. I hope I explained the issue well enough! Thanks

Comment: Keep a `$matches = [];` array, and instead of `return 'Red';` you can do `$matches[] = 'Red';`. Then, at the end of the function, once all matching is done, `return implode(', ', $matches);`

Comment: *"the above code returns Red on ALL strings containing Red."* - I'm honestly not quite sure where the problem is there.

Comment: Deceze, if a string contains 'Red' but also 'Blue', stripos() wil not return Red, Blue. It will return 1 of the 2 colors.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Could you maybe elaborate in a code snippet? I'm not that advanced in PHP to translate this into something I can use yet.. :)

Comment: Then you need to break that string apart at `/` and/or `,`, instead of treating it as one long colour name.

Comment: @deceze That is unavailable unfortunately, as i am importing big files in which each record contains a different color string.

Comment: So how the function is executed:
`function global_colors_mapping ($color) {}`
where `$color` is passed through from the XML import, so this could be `Prism Pink,Racer Pink,Mist Blue,Prism Pink`.

Comment: Not sure why the fact that it's a big file changes anything about the operation.

Comment: @deceze Okay that's a valid point. But how do you break the string up, and then perform a `stripos()` (for example) that `returns` the value `Red, Blue, Black` on the string `Marine Blue, Burgundy Red, Pretty Black`

Comment: You break the string into an array of individual colours, then for each item in the array you do your `stripos` thing and assemble a result array. … Or perhaps you do a completely different approach, like a global regular expression for `/Red|Blue|Black|.../`.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string with `explode()`, then loop over that to return all the color matches. You can use a regular expression instead of `stripos()`.

```
$string = 'Power Red/Collegiate Burgundy/Black Hard/Silver Paradise';
$array = explode('/', $string);
$colors = array_map(function($s) {
    if (preg_match('/red|blue|black|burgundy|silver|pink/i', $s, $match)) {
        return $match[0];
    }
}, $array);
print_r($colors);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/F4QgDz)